# Add class to elments with same matching class as per clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, classname

I need to add an `.active` class to any button which matches any of the classes as per the div I am clicking:

```
<button class="valueA"></button>
<button class="valueB"></button>
<button class="valueC valueB"></button>

<div class="DYNAMIC CLASS"></div>
```

```js
$("div.valueB").on("click", function() {
    ...
});
```

The result should be:

```
<button class="valueB active"></button>
<button class="valueC valueB active"></button>
```

I tried using `.each()` but I'm stack with the comparison of the classes.

The thing is that my div has dynamic class just as well as those buttons, so I don't know what matches until they are in the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One version is to create a click function for every single class that you have in your document. This would look something like this:

```
$('.valueA').click(function() {
  $('.valueA').addClass('active')
})
$('.valueB').click(function() {
  $('.valueB').addClass('active')
})
$('.valueC').click(function() {
  $('.valueC').addClass('active')
})
```

This is repetitive code however and should be avoided. So instead you can create a function that adds click handlers to all buttons (that's the example I wrote) and then retrieves the classes attached to the element. It then loops over the array of classes and adds to every element with that class another one.

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')
  classes.forEach(function(elem) {

    $('.' + elem).addClass('active');
  })
})
```

Now if you want to limit the application of said class then you add the element type that the class should be applied to before the .

```
$('button.' + elem).addClass('active');
```

or

```
$('div.' + elem).addClass('active');
```

Comment: will it not add a class active to the button too? It's fine tho, just asking

Comment: Yes, it will. Edited my response to give more options.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `.each()`. You can do it like following.

```js
$("div").on("click", function() {
    $('button.active').removeClass('active');
    $('button.' + this.className).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="valueA">A</button>
<button class="valueB">B</button>
<button class="valueC valueB">C</button>

<div class="valueA">DIV A</div>
<div class="valueB">DIV B</div>
<div class="valueC">DIV C</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, i didn't write properly my question, updated it now. The thing is the class in the div is dynamic, so i don't know it but it will match classes in the buttons

Comment: `className` is a property, don't need to define. [See this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) @rob.m

Answer (score 1):

You need to get class name of div using [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and use class name in selector.

```js
$("div").on("click", function() {
    var className = $(this).attr("class");
    $('button.'+ className).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active { color: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="valueA">A</button>
<button class="valueB">B</button>
<button class="valueC valueB">CB</button>
<div class="valueB">B</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the name of your divs class and add your `.active` class to all of your buttons by using the corret selector `$('button.valueB')`.

So a dynamic solution could look like this

```
$("div.valueB").on("click", function(e) {
  var className = e.target.className;
  $('button.' + className).addClass('active');
});
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/Aer0/pen/VmYejK)